# Space being used without having any file

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I just created my Ubuntu One account, and I've been testing it (uploading and deleting files), but I realized that I have 836.0 KB being used without having any file. Is this normal? How can i fix this?

I already checked for hidden files in the Ubuntu One folder (the only one i have syncing), but i have none. I also checked in one.ubuntu.com/files but i have the message that says "Let’s get started with syncing your files!" which, I think, it means that I have no files.

Comment: There's no hidden files in your Ubuntu one folder on your PC? or leftovers on the cloud?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my problem fixed. From what I read in the FAQs it is a known [bug](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-is-my-storage-usage-reported-wrong/). For anybody with a similar problem, I suggest sending threw the [Contact Us](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) from the Ubuntu One main page a request similar to my original question and, in my case, they answered quickly and the problem solved immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue. By mistake I chosen to sync a folder. When I realized this I tried to stop the sync but it had already loaded data into the cloud. However, this data is not visible and uses 700mb of my storage!
Is there a way to format Ubuntu-One?
Thanks,

Fabian

Comment: Have you checked for the files online in https://one.ubuntu.com/files/? If you have the message that says "Let’s get started with syncing your files!", meaning that you have NO files, and your account is still using up space then you have exactly the same problem I had. To get it fix you need to send a request threw the Contact Us https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ and they will fix it for you. It is a known buy https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-is-my-storage-usage-reported-wrong/