# My folders in the Ubuntu one cloud are empty, my control panel says I am using 947 MB

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have not folders in the Ubuntu one cloud, my control panel says I am using 947 MB.

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to tell why the reported usage is wrong from the information you've given.  Perhaps it would be best to file a formal support request using the following form:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Please use the same email address in the support request as you use for your Ubuntu One account so we know which account you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, check out my original question for more information: [Space being used without having any file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56903/space-being-used-without-having-any-file)